# Making DTM from contour vectors in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem

I have been using QGIS (2.18.0) for 6 months and now need to make a DEM from contour vectors. From my reading, I know I have to use GRASS.

I am in the process of using this tutorial to achieve that end.

After I run r.surf.contour, I get this:

[image: ![Output after r.surf.contour]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkhN9.png)

No error message, but the dtm_1m in not in the layer tree.

Comment: Do you mean the layer tree in the qgis browser?

Comment: No, I mean the layer tree in GRASS. When I try to add the raster layer (dtm_1m), it is not in the layer tree of the drop down box this pop-up box:

Comment: What mapsets does it show you in the tree?

Comment: Mapset:Ruth with contours and Contours_Dorr AND Mapset:permanent

Comment: Have you checked in the PERMANENT folder. I think I remember the qgis plugin putting grass outputs there.

Comment: Yes, I have been through all the bits in both PERMANENT and Ruth. No luck.

Comment: @Ruth - What about running the `r.surf.contour` algorithm from the **Processing Toolbox** in QGIS?

Comment: @Ruth - Still no output or receiving an error?

Comment: @Joseph Still no output or error message. How lonh would you expect the processing of the dtm to take please? I am getting the above message instantaneously. I would have expected at least part of a second.

Comment: @Ruth - Depends on the DTM, a very simple one for me took a few seconds. Would it be possible for you to share your DTM to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: BTW: please also take a look at http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM

Comment: @Joesph - thanks, but this project has to go on the back burner for some time now.